# How to add a second project to Android Studio from version control (git)

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control

Currently, my settings.gradle file adds another project to my open instance of Android Studio through the following:

```
include ':app', ':other' 
project(':other').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, "../../../path/to/other/app")
```

However, it is getting the content from my local folder system. How can I make it to get the content from a git repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project had some garbage configuration.

On `File > Settings > Version Control`, I just had to **add the correct folder path** to the other project, and **specificy it as git**.

This made the branches appear on `Git > Manage Repositories`.